# When Interpreting "If A, then B" as "A coupled with B" is rational?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, logic, student-question

It is known that the meaning of a conditional statement in fuzzy logic can vary depending on the interpretation and context. As we know, some ones interpret "if A, then B" as "A *coupled* with B" instead of "$\neg A \lor B$" when dealing with fuzzy rules and fuzzy inference systems; for example see the below update part. However, for students who are solely familiar with classical logic, this unconventional perspective may seem puzzling and give rise to various questions such as:

- in which context this interpretation is applicable?
- why we have to use $A \Rightarrow B$ notation and symbols when it means $A \land B$?
- whether it has any relevance in classical logic?
- whether this interpretation can be rational and relevant in everyday human speech?

Can you help me to find answers of above questions? I think that first and last questions are more important and can cause better understanding.

### Update

Mamdani in [An experiment in linguistic synthesis with a fuzzy logic controller](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020737375800022) has said:

> The control rules were implemented by using fuzzy conditional statements, for example "*If PE is $NB$ then HC is $PB$*". The implied relation between the two fuzzy variables `PE` and `HC` is expressed in terms of the cartesian product of the two subsets $NB$ and $PB$. The cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$ is denoted $A \times B$ and is defined by
> $$
> A \times B = \sum\limits_{i} \sum\limits_{j} \min \{ \mu_{A}(u_i), \mu_{B}(v_j) \} \\
> = \sum\limits_{ij} \min u_i v_j
> $$
> where $u$ and $v$ are generic elements of the universes of discourse of $A$ and $B$ respectively.

As you can see, he used $\min (\mu_{A}(x), \mu_{B}(y))$ as interpretation for $A \rightarrow B$, which is

- equal to $A \land B$
- a special case for $T_{norm} (\mu_{A}(x), \mu_{B}(y))$
- not equal to $\neg A \lor B$

In some books, for example "[Neuro-Fuzzy and Soft Computing: A omputational Approach to Learning and Machine Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132610663)" the $T_{norm} (\mu_{A}(x), \mu_{B}(y))$ interpretation is called as "A coupled with B". Although, here the word "coupled" is not so important for me. I wanted to know when that interpretation is rational?

Comment: Which study programme is the student in? As far as I know (but this is not my expertise), fuzzy logic is used in fairly applied ways and many of the motivations come from those applications. Control device for the temperate of a washing machine is what I remember from the fuzzy logic introduction book I once read.

Comment: @Tommi Those are students of A.I. ; but I am looking for a context in which that interpreting is rational there. Also an example in conversations or daily life is useful.

Comment: *As we know interpreting if A, then B as A coupled with B instead of $\neg A \lor B$ is common when dealing with fuzzy rules and fuzzy inference systems.*...you need to provide a reference for this, or more context. Do we really know this?

Comment: @user52817 I have no reference for that. I said that; because I see that interpretation for $A \Rightarrow B$ is only used there.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you say that "if A then B" can be interpreted as "A coupled with B". I don't even know what "coupled with" means in this context. However I know that in probability, when you write a sentence describing probabilities in English rather than using P(...) symbols, it's very easy to write ambiguous sentences that could mean *any* of P(A|B), P(B|A) or P(A and B), especially using words "if" and "then".

Comment: @Stef I edited my question. Please see it again.